# Add Google Analytics to public cv

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I'd love to be able to see where the hits on my public cv are coming from.  Would it be possible to integrate Google Analytics with careers.stackoverflow.com in the future to get a better idea of who is taking a look?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative that will work straight away would be to use [TrackMyCV.com](http://www.trackmycv.com/), which allows you to embed a 1-pixel tracking image into your CV, like the ones spammers put in their e-mails.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I was hoping to get some information about where the hits were coming from though (the traffic sources), which this site doesn't seem to list.  It shouldn't be that hard to whip up my own service that sends the tracking information to google analytics though using the same image embedding idea though.

Comment: This can never give you referer information *in theory* (the referer for the image will be the URL of your CV page). You can't do much about it.

Comment: Do you have any new info about google analytics integration with the pubblic CV profile on careers.stackoverflow.com ? great thanks